# Print different pages of an excel sheet with different columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook which has multiple sheets. Each sheet has 2 sections KPIS and summary (one below the other). I have used page breaks to ensure that they print on different pages. I have to print columns A1 to L200; however, columns B, E, H should be hidden for KPIs section and few other columns should be hidden for summary section i.e. visible and hidden columns in these 2 sections are overlapping.

The objective is to create a pdf with multiple pages for only visible columns

Here is the code. Here I am hiding and unhiding columns. but I don't have any clue how I can control columns in a page under the same sheet

```
Sub Hide_Rows_Report_Template(HideRange As Range)
        For Each c In HideRange
                    If c.Value > 0 Then
                        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    End If
        Next c
End Sub

Sub UnHide_Rows_Report_Template(HideRange As Range)
        For Each c In HideRange
           c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Next c
End Sub

Sub call_hide_Rows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call UnHide_Rows_Report_Template(Range("Hide1"))


    Call Hide_Rows_Report_Template(Range("Hide_Range"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub call_Unhide_Rows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call UnHide_Rows_Report_Template(Range("Hide1"))


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub print_page()

Call UnHide_Rows_Report_Template(Range("Hide1"))

Call Hide_Rows_Report_Template(Range("Hide1"))

ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bigben.. i have updated my post with the code

Comment: Depending on which pdf print driver you're using, you may be able to append successive prints to the same file.  That way you'd set up and print each area in turn.

Comment: Hi Chris,

I am using adobe pdf option from the list of printers to create a pdf.

Request you to share any article on how to append successive prints to the same pdf.

Comment: [Look here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2162507&ved=2ahUKEwjzm4yAhvTjAhUVIbcAHcbUDiwQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2LNZzwDunwdP7FauxymjOI&cshid=1565293904864) this link says Adobe can't do it, but suggests a few others that can